# TypeError: db.findWConditionandler is not a function MongoDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

This is actually a continuation of my previous question and I'm reasking as I've realised I didn't quite ask the question problem and now I have a different error response.

This is in db.js, a separate file while I have the handlers.
Context: I return `func` like this so that in my index.js, I can continue to perform mongodb `sort` operation to find users with the smallest timestamp!

[image]

[image]

In my server console, I get this response.`TypeError: db.findWConditionandler is not a function` I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Pls advice! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because `.sort` expects a cursor and `.findOne()` doesn't not give a cursor. Instead, one should use `.find()`